# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_autoflush' in SQLAlchemy Query().filter_by().all() object

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, nonetype, autoflush

having trouble in sqlAlchemy query when getting all data from table
it raise error when i use .**all()** mathod

here is error:

```
File "./individual/admin/handler.py", line 69, in test_account_indiv
    query = Query(User).filter_by(account_type="INDIVIDUAL", is_deleted=0).all()
  File "/home/awaiskaleem/Documents/backend-api-develop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3341, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/home/awaiskaleem/Documents/backend-api-develop/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3502, in __iter__
    self.session._autoflush()
**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_autoflush'**
```

here is code:

```
query = Query(User).filter_by(account_type="INDIVIDUAL", is_deleted=0).all()

rows = query.with_session(session)

    only = ("id", "full_name", "status", "default_address.id", "default_address.region.id",
            "default_address.region.name", "tags.tag", "tags.hex_color",
            "assigned_region_workers.region_worker.worker.id",
            "assigned_region_workers.region_worker.worker.full_name")

    schema = UserSchema(only=only, many=True)

    result = schema.dump(rows)
```

here is connection:

```
session_maker = sessionmaker()

USER = os.getenv('DB_USER')
PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
URL = os.getenv('DB_URL')
DB = os.getenv('DB_NAME')

try:
    logger.info("Attempting connect to: mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s/%s", USER, PASSWORD, URL, DB)
    engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (USER, PASSWORD, URL, DB), pool_size=1)
    engine.connect()
    logger.info("Connected to: mysql+pymysql://%s:%s@%s/%s", USER, PASSWORD, URL, DB)
    
except SQLAlchemyError as error:
    logger.error("Error connecting to DB")
    logger.error(error)
else:
    session_maker.configure(bind=engine)

Session = session_maker()
```

i am developing AWS Lembda based Serverless Project on localhost with MySQL databse and SQLAlchemy ORM model
everything is setup on virtual envirnment using dockers in ubuntu

plz help me
thanks for advance

looking foreword for positive response

Comment: `session` is `None`. How are you creating `session`?

Comment: this is not a complete code it is some part of code where error occured.
session is werking fine everywhere in project

Comment: actually i want to query the calculated field which is not in database.it is created runtime.